# Beego must have one register DataBase alias named `default`

Tags: go, beego

In the production server with Beego I get

must have one register DataBase alias named `default`

I know the db connection credentials work in the server but whenever I do restful request I get this error and the Beego server crashes.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Below is the code inside main.go init function:

```
orm.RegisterDriver("postgres", orm.DR_Postgres)

orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "postgres",
    fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%s:%s@%s/%s?port=%i",
        pgUser, pgPass, pgHost, pgDb, pgPort))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a sample of your code?

Based on the error message you have provided, you may not have registered a database with alias `default` using `orm.RegisterDataBase`. Here's an example which I have taken from the [documentation](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md#registerdatabase):

```
// param 1:        Database alias. ORM will use it to switch database.
// param 2:        driverName
// param 3:        connection string
orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", "root:root@/orm_test?charset=utf8")
```

In beego, it is common to register the driver and the database in `init` of `main.go` [(example)](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md#main.go).

Comment: I just updated my question. I have RegisterDatabase under init function already

Comment: Interesting thing is that same thing works on dev environment but does not on prod with similar settings. DB credentials work fine

Comment: I'm assuming there are no other errors besides what you've reported. If it's possible, may I see how you are using the ORM? `RegisterDatabase` also returns an `error`, so you could try capturing that although that shouldn't be necessary (as it should already be handled). Besides that, are you using any environment specific config / conditions?

Comment: Never mind. It was due to PG SSL mode being enabled. I disabled it in the connection string and it worked fine.

Comment: same issue. db registered with "default' BUT NOT WORKING.

Comment: Yeah, still not working for me. Here's my connecting config: `orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "postgres", "root:rootroot@localhost/project_development?sslmode=disable")`, This is the error i get: `register db Ping `default`, pq: SSL is not enabled on the server`

Comment: Figured it out, here's a working example: `orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "postgres", "postgres://root:rootroot@localhost/project_development?sslmode=disable")`