# Beego ORM MySql Connection Error

Tags: go, orm, beego

I am use beego framework. I am getting the error "Must have one register DataBase alias nameddefault "in ORM mysql connection

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894796/beego-must-have-one-register-database-alias-named-default

Comment: same issue myself. trying to follow the docs to a t but still wont work.